# Защита от хакинга в input

Tags: javascript, jquery, взлом

есть форма input и его значение получается через $("#input").val() а потом выводиться через создание параграфа, но если ввести что-то на подобии alert("i am hacker") этот код будет выполнен, есть ли способы чтобы это val() брало информацию как text(). а не html()?

```
function printMsg(text, className, type){
  this.clsName = className;
  this.txt = text;
  if(this.txt){
  if(type == "html"){
    $('#chatbox').before(`<p class="${clsName}" id="${msgs}">${this.txt}</p>`);
    
  }
  else{
    $('#chatbox').before(`<p class="${clsName}" id="${msgs}">${this.txt}</p>`);
    
    
  }
  msgs++;
  }
}
function printClient(){
  
  printMsg($("#input").val(), "client", "text");
  $("#input").val('');
  return false;
  
}
```

Comment: Не в ту сторону воюете. Вам нужно, чтобы какой бы текст ни прилетел к обычному участнику чата, он не стал бы исполняемым. Т.е. проблема не там, где input.value, а там, где chat.before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

присваивай значение через `.text()`

```
   let p_var= $('<p>', {'class': className});
   p_var.text('<script language="Javascript">alert("hi");</'+ 'script>');
   $('#chatbox').before(p_var)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, всё теперь работает как надо, кроме класса), но это сам исправлю.

Comment: добавил класс в ответ)